# AttributeError at /admin/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

This is the error I got and i am not able to get the admin login screen.

> AttributeError at /admin/
>   'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
>   Django Version: 2.1.2
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py in has_permission, line 186
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Neptune\Desktop\MyMusic',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages',
>    'C:\Users\Neptune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.7.egg']
>   Server time:    Tue, 4 Jun 2019 17:37:30 +0000

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in the `settings.py`, can you post that also in this question

Comment: Piggybacking on @SammyJ's comment--the `user` attribute is normally added to requests by middlewear (specifically `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`), so the `MIDDLEWARE` of your `settings.py` would be the first place to look.  (See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware)

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
] @Sammy J this is my setting.py middleware section of code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment it seems you are doing a mistake in your settings, in Django 2.0 and above the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is changed to only `MIDDLEWARE` so the middleware should be like

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

link about this in the docs, [check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware)  and please be careful, if you are new to django then it is good to learn from the docs, there are many tutorials for django which are too outdated.

You could start from here [gettting started page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/)

Comment: Thnaks for your support @Sammy J. But the Django version which i use is 1.9.1 and not its 2.0

Comment: Are you sure @Iswarian because I'm the error log you posted it's showing Django version 2.1.2

Comment: Thanks for your extended support. Got fixed after changing the middleware_classes to middleware and deleting this line from the middleware settings : 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'

Comment: Glad to hear that, can you accept this answer, maybe someone facing the same issue in the future can benefit from this :)